# Play's default Security Authentication Filter not hit

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I am trying to implement the Play's Authentication by extending the `Security.Authenticator` class. I am using Play 2.4.2 (Damiya ) and here is my code.

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator{

    public Secured() {
        Logger.info("In secured constructor....");
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context context) {
        return context.session().get("loggedin_user");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context context) {
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
}
```

I think this class which extends Security.Authenticator acts as J2EE filter intercepting every single request. But I haven't seen a single time the constructor logger printed. Correct me if I misunderstood the concept of Security.Authenticator, let me know how it works.

I tried to use `@Security.Authenticated` on top of one of the action method in controller and the class is not even compiling despite throwing the following compile time error.

```
package Security does not exist Security.Authenitcated
```

I guess some library is missing, Is the process of Play's Authentication changed in Play 2.4.2 version? Does this Secured class filters all requests checking for authentication?

**Update:**
After keeping the @Authenticated annotation from `play.mvc.Security.Authenticated` on top the action method in controller request is filtered at Secured class. I noticed that each time request is passed through the Security class, it's constructors logger message is printed. Does it mean each time a new Secured object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import **Security.Authentification** or **play.mvc.Security.Authenticator**

in the case of

```
import Security.Authentification;
```

I receive

```
Compilation error[package Security does not exist]
```

In the case of

```
import play.mvc.Security.Authenticator;
```

All works as expected. So I am pretty sure you just do wrong import.

**Update:** "*I noticed that each time request is passed through the Security class, it's constructors logger message is printed. Does it mean each time a new Secured object is created?*"

Yes. I check the [Play source code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/c7d4bd257f7963401ef7459abe50ddd4222d61ce/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Security.java) and verify that it creates new instance each time request is passed.

```
 Authenticator authenticator = injector.instanceOf(configuration.value());
 String username = authenticator.getUsername(ctx);
```

Comment: Yes, I was using **play.mvc.Security.Authenticator** earlier, but as I was using @Security.Authenticated it wasn't working in Play 2.4.2. Updated my question.

Comment: I verified this code in the Play 2.4.2 - it works exactly in the same way as on 2.4.0

Comment: What worked for me is by just importing this **import play.mvc.Security;**
the annotation **@Security.Authenticated** has worked.

Comment: I verified your Secured class in my 2.4.2 project - it works, so I am not pretty sure what issues do you has still.

Comment: Check my Update in question.

Comment: Check my Update in answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89667/discussion-between-srk-and-andriy-kuba).

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware you have found your answer for your question but in case of you want to use an injected service in your `Security.Authenticator` implementation which you probably will (because Play 2.4.* uses DI), you will get injection errors. This was an issue for **Play 2.4.2** and solved in new **Play 2.4.3** version. I suggest you to upgrade your version of Play.
The issue can be found in this [link](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2188#issuecomment-138443250).

As an example something like this, will cause an error in 2.4.2, but not in 2.4.3;

```
@Singleton
public class SecurityGuard extends Security.Authenticator {

    String message;       

    @Inject
    Response response;  // injected play service

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {
       // removed code
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context ctx) {
        return response.unauthorized(message);
    }

}
```